# Showing a function has first and second partials everywhere and continuity of the partials

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x \\
y \end{array} \right)=  \begin{cases} 
xy\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}  & \mbox{if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$}\\
0 &    \mbox{if $(x,y) = (0,0)$} \end{cases}. $

I have this function and I want to show it's first and second partials exist everywhere, the first partials are continuous and the seconds are not. Computing the partials is one thing but what Do i do about continuity?

Here are the first partials:

away from $0$

$$D_1(f) = \large\frac{4x^2y^3 + x^4y-y^5}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

$$D_2(f) = \large\frac{x^5-4x^3y^2-xy^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

Comment: If you've computed the partials, continuity follows easily. Any partial derivative in $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ is continuous. To check at $(0,0)$ take limit of the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ and see if it coincides with the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @GitGud the second partials aren't continuous though.

Comment: They are in $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: The domain here is $\mathbb{R}^2$ though.

Comment: Yes and I told you how to investigate on $\mathbb R^2$ in my first comment. What didn't you understand?

Comment: @GitGud no,  I see now. Just that multi-dimensional limits are quite difficult. How would you show that $D_1(f)$ has limit $0$ as $x,y$ go to $0$?

Comment: Help me help you: add the partial derivatives to your question.

Comment: @GitGud done, i have added both D1 and D2

Comment: Ah! Thanks, but this is leaves me wondering if you know to find them at $(0,0)$. This is crucial in solving the problem. The first one is trivial, the second possibly involves a little more work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14052/discussion-between-terrible-at-math-and-git-gud)

Comment: I do know how to find them it's just a pain in the neck, but i'll do it out.

Comment: I do believe you, but by showing your work the question will be more complete for future reference and it will be easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll handle $D_1(f)$.

Let $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$.

Note that 
$$\begin{align} 
|D_1(f)(x,y)|&=\left|\dfrac {y\left(x^4+4x^2y^2-y^4\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}\right|\\
&\leq \dfrac {y\left(x^4+4x^2y^2+y^4\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{y\left(\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2+2x^2y^2\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}\\
&=y+\dfrac{2x^2y^3}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}.\\
\end{align}$$

Thus. to prove that $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(D_1(f)(x,y)\right)=0$, it is enough to prove that $$\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(y+\dfrac{2x^2y^3}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}\right)=0.$$

In turn, to prove this, it enough to prove that $$\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(y\right)=0 \land \lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(\dfrac{2x^2y^3}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}\right)=0.$$

This is a consequence of

$$\dfrac{2x^2y^3}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}=\dfrac{2x^2y^3}{x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4}\leq \dfrac{2x^2y^3}{2x^2y^2}=y\substack{(x,y)\to (0,0)\\\huge\longrightarrow} 0.$$

Therefore, if $D_1(f)(0,0)=0$, then $D_1(f)$ is continuous. If $D_1(f)(0,0)\neq 0$, it is discontinuous at the origin.

Since $D_1(f)(y,x)=-D_2(f)(x,y)$, the same conclusions follow immediately for $D_2(f)$.

Comment: thank you, this helps a lot. to compute a derivative via limits with multi dimensions: do i have to do partials again?

Comment: @terribleatmath If you want to know about $D_{11}(f)$ and $D_{12}(f)$, yes. I'm going to bed soon, though. So I'll probably just take a look at it tomorrow.